# How can I plot an infinite series with two variables with legends?

Tags: series-expansion

I want to sketch the graph of this series [image]

Comment: Please paste copy&pastable code instead of screenshots. It is not fair to the people who are trying to assist to make them need to retype all your content based on some images.

Comment: Could you show what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

First experiment with partial sum,

```
Clear[C0, CA, l, x, t, rho, a, b, D1];

C1[x_, t_, C0_, CA_, l_, rho_, a_, b_, D1_, 
  N1_] := (C0 - CA)*
   Sum[Sec[n*(Pi - l)]*Cos[n*(x + Pi - l)]*Exp[(-D1*n^2 + rho)*t], {n,
      0, N1}] + a*Exp[b*t]/(rho - b) + CA

Plot3D[C1[x, t, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 10], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]